# What things are restricted during the 3 weeks?

Tags: halacha, minhag, three-weeks

There are [a lot of questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/three-weeks) here on Mi Yodeya about specific restrictions during the three weeks between 17 Tammuz and 9 Av, but I would like to know all of the things that are forbidden during the three weeks.

Comment: According to whom?

Comment: Is this answerable in less than a book?

Answer (score 4):

Nitei Gavriel Bain HaMatzarim [page 101](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46439&st=&pgnum=101) says that one may get engaged during the period of 17 Tamuz - 29 Tamuz, however no music or dancing is allowed.

[Page 102](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46439&st=&pgnum=102) says that according to Ashkenazik custom we do not get married the entire 3 weeks, however Sefardic custom is to allow weddings during the period of 17 Tamuz - 29 Tamuz.

[Page 105](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46439&st=&pgnum=105) says that one is not allowed to listen to music the entire 3 weeks, however on [page 107](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46439&st=&pgnum=107) he says that for the Sefardim that get married up to 29 Tamuz they may play music at their Chasunos.

[Page 116](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46439&st=&pgnum=116) says that one should not dedicate a new Sefer Torah the entire 3 weeks.

[Page 119](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46439&st=&pgnum=119) says that since we do not make a Shehechiyanu on new clothing therefore one may purchase new clothing up to 29 Tamuz.

[Page 125](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46439&st=&pgnum=125) says that one may say Shehechiyanu for a new daughter and for a Pidyon HaBen.

[Page 126](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46439&st=&pgnum=126) One may move to a new apartment during these days, however it is best not to.

[Page 129](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46439&st=&pgnum=129) says that no hair cutting is allowed the entire three weeks, however Sefardim only keep this during the week of Tisha B'Av.

Comment: Please everybody, add on anything that was left off.

Comment: Anything left off from Nitei Gavriel, or anything left off in general?

Comment: This issue of Halachically Speaking could be useful: http://thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol5Issue13.pdf

Comment: @DoubleAA: anything left off in general. Or anything one deems important.