# Starting a new job in the Three Weeks

Tags: halacha, minhag, employment, three-weeks

In response to ["What things are restricted in the 3 weeks"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29604/what-things-are-restricted-during-the-3-weeks) there is no mention of a restriction to start a new job. Is there a source that recommends that one should not start a new job in the 3 weeks if possible?

Comment: I believe that somewhere O.C. recommends not making major business deals during the 9 days. But, I wouldn't consider starting a job as a business deal, unless you're Donald Trump ;-) Generally, the things prohibited during the 9 Days (which are much stricter than the rest of the 3 weeks period) relate to "danger" or "bad omens". I would think that starting a new job is a good thing, and, it's probably esp. allowable if one would lose the opportunity if he doesn't take it immediately. Esp. if one is poor or unemployed.